# Singular values of a bidiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:** Show that if the entries on both principal diagonals of a bidiagonal matrix $A$ are all nonzero, then the singular values of the matrix are distinct.

**Possible approach:** The result follows from the fact that a tridiagonal Hermitian matrix with nonzero diagonals (main, sub and super), has distinct eigenvalues. (Then if $A$ is bidiagonal, $A^TA$ is of such a form, and the singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.)

Still remains to prove the latter. 
Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that theorem, you can check directly that if $A$ has main diagonal $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ and super-diagonal $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$, then $A^*A$ is tri-diagonal with main diagonal $|\alpha_11|^2,|\alpha_2|^2+|\beta_2|^2,\ldots,|\alpha_n|^2+|\beta_n|^2$, super-diagonal $\overline{\beta_1}\alpha_1,\ldots,\overline{\beta_{n-1}}\alpha_{n-1}$, and sub-diagonal conjugate to the upper diagonal.